# Method with generic return type but not generic input. Is this possible?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, generic-programming, type-parameter

Suppose we have a `NodeData` class:

```
public class NodeData<T>
{
    public string Name;
    public T Value;
    public NodeData(string name, T value)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Value = value;
    }
}
```

And a base `Node` class and child classes that have several properties with type `NodaData`:

```
public class Node
{
    public List<NodeData<T>> listOutputs<T>()
    {
        var fieldInfos = GetType().GetFields();
        var list = new List<NodeData<T>>();
        foreach (var item in fieldInfos)
        {
            Type t = item.FieldType;
            string name = item.Name;
            if (t == typeof(NodeData<T>))
            {
                var output = new NodeData<T>(name, default(T));
                list.Add(output);
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
}

public class TestNode : Node {
    public NodeData<int> data;
    public NodeData<double> data2;
    public NodeData<double> data3;
    public TestNode ()
    {
        data = new NodeData<int>("test", 111);
        data2 = new NodeData<double>("test", 113);
    }
}
```

As you can see there is a method which lists all outputs with type `T` in the `Node` class So I can find what are the output fields of the child class in runtime:

```
TestNode node = new TestNode ();
var list = node.listOutputs<int>(); // this returns data
```

But I need to know how to use this method to list all NodeOutputs of any type T. In this example `int` and `double`. Do I need to add a method with this signature `public List<NodeData<T>> listOutputs() // should return all properties data, data2, data3`. Is it possible to have method like this? return type is generic but there is no type argument for method.

Comment: That doesn't actually make sense; there is no compile-time type for the return type.  You should add a non-generic base class or interface.

Comment: Add something like a non-generic `NodeDataBase` type or a `INodeData` that `NodeData<T>` will implement. Then set your return to that type.

Comment: Also, what are you actually trying to accomplish here? Because using reflection to get the types of fields from your class here seems wrong. If you could describe you ultimate objective a little better, there is probably a better way to approach it.

Comment: @MattBurland Thanks for your comments. Could you possibly review the question again, I edited and added more detail.

Comment: are you saying that you won't know what type to use with `listOutputs<T>` until runtime?  If that's the case, you might want to pass a `Type` in as a parameter

Comment: @SamIam If I run `listOutputs<int>()` I get all fields with parameter type int. But I need to get all fields with any parameter type. `double` or `int` or any others that may exist it `TestNode`.

Comment: @SamIam I tested `node.listOutputs<Type>();` But nothing returned! The list was empty.

Comment: @a.toraby I meant something more like this:  `public Object listOutputs(Type type)`

Comment: Don't use templates for this -- if you want a `List<object>` just use `List<object>`.  If you want a sub-list of one type use OfType() on your list.

Comment: Also note: use public properties rather than fields.

Answer (score 1):

Even after your edit(s) it is not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve but here are my assumptions:
-You want to have some kind of Node object that acts as a container for different types of NodeData elements.
-You want to be able to return one list from this Node object that contains all NodeData elements stored in the Node container, regardless of the NodeData objects' type.

Instead of returning a List> object from the listOutputs methods, just return the non-generic version of the List object. Then you don't have to deal with T in the method call.

The logic that loops through the objects in the non-generic list can then examine the type to process the contained NodeData objects correctly.

Important note: My proposed solution is by no means pretty but I think it answers the question. In my opinion something is already seriously flawed from an OO point of view in the presented code (e.g. use of reflection) and a better solution would have to start by changing the underlying data structures. But that can only be done if we have more information how this is to be used, e.g. what kind of logic consumes the returned list.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a base interface that will be used to return the generic data.

```
public interface INodeData
{
    string Name { get; }
}
public class NodeData<T> : INodeData
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public T Value { get; private set; }

    public NodeData(string name, T value)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Value = value;
    }
}
```

I modified the function to return a list of the interface. Doing this you won't depend on `T`.

```
public class Node
{
    public List<INodeData> listOutputs()
    {
        var fieldInfos = GetType().GetFields();
        var list = new List<INodeData>();
        foreach (var item in fieldInfos)
        {
            INodeData data = GetType().GetField(item.Name).GetValue(this) as INodeData;
            list.Add(data);    
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

If you test the method, it should return the fields in a list. To work with a specific type, you can make use of `is` before using the type you search for.

```
public class TestNode : Node
{
    public NodeData<int> data;
    public NodeData<double> data2;
    public NodeData<double> data3;

    public TestNode()
    {
        data = new NodeData<int>("test", 111);
        data2 = new NodeData<double>("test", 113);
    }
}

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TestNode node = new TestNode();
    var list = node.listOutputs(); // this returns data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may well be an XY problem, in that you probably want to rethink how you are designing your classes because using reflection in this way doesn't seem right. But give the problem you've presented, I'd tackle it like this:

```
public abstract class NodeDataBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public NodeData(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    // this isn't actually needed, but might be helpful
    public abstract object GetValue();

}


public class NodeData<T> : NodeDataBase
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public NodeData(string name, T value) : base(name)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public override object GetValue()
    {
        return Value;
    }
}
```

And now your method signature would be:

```
public List<NodeDataBase> listOutputs()
```

And with the list returned, you can use the `GetValue` method to get the actual values without needing to cast to the right generic type to be able to get at the `Value` property.

You could also just have a return type of `List<object>`, but then you'll have to cast each member of that list to the right generic type before you can access it's properties.

You can also avoid that nasty reflection code, instead of having `data`, `data1`, and `data2`, you could simply do this in your `Node` class:

```
public class Node
{
    public List<NodeDataBase> Data { get; protected set; }

    public Node()
    {
        Data = new List<NodeDataBase>();
    }
}
```

And now you don't even need your `listOutputs` method because you can just get the list from the node (unless you actually wanted a copy, but that's fairly trivial to implement).

And you `TestNode` would be just:

```
public class TestNode : Node {
    public TestNode ()
    {
        Data.Add(new NodeData<int>("test", 111));
        Data.Add(new NodeData<double>("test", 113));
    }
}
```