# I need to create an object of Class<T> but I dont know the T And my plan is to find T using generics but I dont know how

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, generic-programming, system.reflection

Suppose we have a `NodeInput` class like this:

```
public class NodeInput
{

}
public sealed class NodeInput<T> : NodeInput
{

}
```

And we have a `Node` class as follows:

```
public abstract class Node
{
    public Node()
    {
        var fieldInfos = GetType().GetRuntimeFields();
        // loop through all NodeInputs using their concrete base type
        foreach (var item in fieldInfos)
        {
            Type t = item.FieldType;
            if (t.BaseType == typeof(NodeInput))
            {
                // Here I want to initialize each NodeInput field according to
                // the T but I don't know what the T is here. 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have created the concrete parent class `NodeInput` so I can numerate all `NodeInput<T>` regardless of their `T` parameter type. But I also need the `T` to create the appropriate object and assign to each field in the loop.
For an example `PointNode` in the following code should initiate all `NodeInput` fields with `default(T)` when we create an object of that:

```
 public class PointNode : Node
{
    public NodeInput<double> x;
    public NodeInput<int> y;
    public NodeInput<float> z;
}
PointNode node = new PointNode (); 
// Now x,y and z should be 0 = default(double),default(int),default(float)
```

Is that possible?

Comment: This question is very similar to another question of yours (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31388962/method-with-generic-return-type-but-not-generic-input-is-this-possible). Just like before I seriously doubt the design approach that you are taking here. Can you please describe at a higher level what problem you are trying to solve? To be more specific about my concerns: For proper encapsulation and loose coupling, only NodeInput should have to know how to populate its members, not the Node or any other class.

Comment: Better would be to put this in the `Node<T>` constructor. That would remove the need for reflection and enforce type safety.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you can get node generic type like this:

```
var genericType = item.FieldType.GenericTypeArguments[0];
```